# background-repeat: no-repeat; is not working

Tags: css, background, background-image

Restricting the height of the body to 100% of the screen height you will see background-repeat: no-repeat; not working.

How is, or would this be fixed in the code? https://jsfiddle.net/z3gq0y5x/

Why is the background still repeating?

How would that be fixed in the code?

I am using `background-repeat: no-repeat;` yet that is not working in the code.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.bg1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #102eff, #d2379b);
}

.bg2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #102eff, #d2379b);
}

.bg3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #102eff, #d2379b);
}
```

[image]

It can also be seen in the snippet I provided.

```js
(function randomBackground() {
  const classNames = [
    "bg1",
    "bg2",
    "bg3"
  ];

  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * classNames.length);
  document.querySelector("body").classList.add(classNames[random]);
}());



const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const config = {};
  let player = null;

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const frameContainer = document.querySelector(".video");
    videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer, config.playlist);
  }

  function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    player.playVideoAt(0);
    player.stopVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
    shufflePlaylist(player);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, playlist) {

    const config = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      width: 640
    };
    config.playerVars = {
      autoplay: 0,
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      loop: 1,
      playlist,
      rel: 0
    };
    config.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };
    player = new YT.Player(video, config);

  }

  function init(videos) {
    config.playlist = videos.join();
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer,
    init
  };
}());

videoPlayer.init([
  "CHahce95B1g",
  "CHahce95B1g",
  "CHahce95B1g",
  "CHahce95B1g"
]);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.bg1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #102eff, #d2379b);
}

.bg2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #102eff, #d2379b);
}

.bg3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #102eff, #d2379b);
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: fade 10s ease-in 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

iframe {
  user-select: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="tcell">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**The answer below gives me this:**

[image]

2nd updated answer provided:

The updated answer causes the video to no-longer be centered in the middle.

The video was originally centered in the middle in the question I posted.

The answer that was provided messed that up.

**Seen Here:**
[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: Restricting the height of the body to 100% of the screen height you will see background-repeat: no-repeat; not working.

Comment: Your background repeat is in `body::before` but your background image is in `body.bg1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to the `body`, and not to the `body::before`. Also add `min-height: 100%`to your `html`

```
html{
  min-height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The purpose of the .container is to center the video vertically.

Here is also the html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="tcell">
      <div class="video-wrapper">
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect but remove height may cause incorrect background on other screen size.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed, problem solved. Body keeps the height of 100%, but is removed from html. Thank you for pointing it out  =)

Comment: That does not work. Look: https://i.imgur.com/HZqZ1Cc.png Code: https://jsfiddle.net/1kyhmapb/

Comment: @EricaLevine @erecodes Remove `height: 100%;` from body. Set `min-height: 100%;` to `html` only.

Comment: Update your answer.

Comment: @vee Can you show me it working in the code because now the video is no-longer centered in the middle. Seen Here: https://i.imgur.com/RJJZbyd.png

Comment: The updated answer causes the video to no-longer be centered in the middle. Seen Here: https://i.imgur.com/RJJZbyd.png

Comment: Hey Erica, previous result for me wasn't centered either. Centering elements vertically is a completely different topic and you should check it out from here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/how-can-i-vertically-align-elements-in-a-div

Comment: The video was originally centered in the middle in my Question I posted. https://jsfiddle.net/z3gq0y5x/ The answer that was provided messed that up.

Comment: @EricaLevine https://jsfiddle.net/v1sm3eL5/ Change the way of `min-height` in `html` and `body`. Add display `flex` to vertical center contents.

Comment: Erica, I made an update with a quick fix for vertical alignment. Wrap the player inside the container div.

Comment: @EricaLevine I edited a bit the code, knowing you need to align it vertically changes a bit the code. Your image which looks like the video is centered is actually not, if you look it trough the inspector. It is centered with the background, but not actually with the page. So when we fixed the original issue, which was the background repeating, it also made the issue with vertical alignment visible, since the page was not just the size of your content, but actually the whole page.